# How to make Drupal STOP stripping away <a> tags

Tags: input-formats

Very simple HTML submitted in "Full HTML" mode via the editor (rich text disabled).

Not only does Drupal smash all the empty space, the also strips away the  tag wrapping a div.

```
<a href="about">
  <!--Panel1 Code - Image 960/600-->
  <div class="fp-hero" style="background-image:url(/sites/default/files/fp_p1_r2.jpg)">
    <div id="fp-hero-tagline">
      <h2>The Institute for Disease Modeling</h2>
      <h1>develops</h1>
      <p>quantitative decision-making tools for the eradication and control of infectious diseases</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: The code is not valid HTML. You are not supposed to put block type elements in an `<a>` tag. It's possible the browser that corrects that.

Comment: According this it is valid...
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

Comment: Correct you are, if your page validates as HTML5. Links should be allowed by default, but check your text formats to make sure nothing is stripped out.

Comment: This might be a known issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1333730